# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION building Android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I shared a project with a mate via SVN , the first time that i upgrade, it works, but every time that I do an upgrade or revert appears the same error, the project fail at build, in my other personal projects it did not happen.

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Desarrollo\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-4cd969c5a2336e63047b8ffdfe0b5c92cf458361.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-5b2459de5b6d6da358967ca597c9aabd60f181f2.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-93c27da75290c72ca476199e4d33e535dc0bf965.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\ormlite-android-4.48-4f3cc0124d8eff4f2073ff3a46792cfc91b2624f.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\ormlite-core-4.48-0bd95a1a663c4fb0739f1301182b5ca19716a32d.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-1d2f24f516d954aa629536574454148d4ea5ab29.jar C:\Users\fnac\AndroidStudioProjects\TouristProject\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.1.0-dac73c3265d0201b25f957879432f8f58282790b.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

    Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was obvious, how i can fix it, the proyect cant build

Comment: Don't think subversion has anything to do with the problem you are having.   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback; at

Comment: @RobGoodwin maybe, but, again, how i fix it?

Comment: @xoelus This usually happens when you are referencing the same dependency more than once.  I had the error when I had an ant build generate a jar file of the same code that was being referenced on the class path in an eclipse build.  So the same objects were being pulled in from 2 different sources.  A search on that exception brings up 3 stack overflow questions about this.  Without seeing your entire source tree and knowing how it is built, it is hard to say exactly how to fix it.  But if you look at the other stack overflow question, you will see a common pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have lots of jar files duplicated.

Someone uploaded the `app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug` directory to svn, and now you have duplicates.

Shouldn't upload that directory. Delete it.